# Aliases not working in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case

This will work fine in MySQL 5:

```
SELECT INSTR(foo, 'Bar') as foobar
FROM Table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN foobar = 1 THEN foo END DESC;
```

Bu in MySQL 4, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'foobar' in 'order clause'
```

However, if I change the clause to this, it will work on both versions:

```
SELECT INSTR(foo, 'Bar') as foobar
FROM Table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN INSTR(foo, 'Bar') = 1 THEN foo END DESC;
```

To ensure compatibility, do I have to always use the second way?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799558/invalid-column-name-order-by-on-alias-of-subquery

Comment: thanks @stackmonster, I didn't know how to describe the error.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you cannot re-use a column alias at the same "query-level".

If you want to be write compatible/portable SQL and don't want to repeat the function call, then the usual way to do it, is to wrap the query into a derived table.

```
select *
from (
  SELECT INSTR(foo, 'Bar') as foobar,
         foo
  FROM Table
) t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN foobar = 1 THEN foo END DESC;
```

Note that you need to include any column you want to use in the "outer" query inside the inner query. If you omit the column `foo` in the inner derived table, you can *not* access it on the outer level.

Answer (score 1):

because `foobar` is an alias. it is not a column unless it's from derived query (*subquery*).like thisone below

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
   SELECT INSTR(foo, 'Bar') as foobar
   FROM Table
) a
ORDER BY CASE WHEN foobar = 1 THEN foo END DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per other answers, you can not use alias in `CASE`.
Instead of using sub-query you can direct use `INSTR()` in `CASE` like this:

```
SELECT INSTR(foo, 'Bar') as foobar
FROM Table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN INSTR(foo, 'Bar') = 1 THEN foo END DESC;
```

When you are using sub-query then note that you will also have to select `foo` column to order by it, other wise you will get an error [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e44e/3)

So your query with sub-query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT foo,INSTR(foo, 'Bar') as foobar
    FROM t
) A
ORDER BY CASE WHEN foobar = 1 THEN foo END DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already had this solution, and I thought that could be a better way of doing it. The other answers cover why I can't reuse `foobar`.

Comment: @ViniciusMassuchetto That's fine :). But see the updated answer for additional notes.