# SQL ORDER BY distance not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, google-maps, geolocation

For the result on my page I need to order the results by distance. The page gets the current position of the user and retrieves the closest 30 results of that position.

Next to the order of the distance I also want to order the results for every `venue` by price.

Problem is that the price order works, but not the distance order. I can't figure out how my function is ordering the results because there is no structure in it (sometimes the closest result is on the last placing, sometimes it is in the middle, sometimes in the beginning, it's really weird).

My SQL statement looks like that:

```
$lat = '48.213688';
$lng = '16.408229';

$sql = "SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(venue_address_lat)) * cos(radians(venue_address_lng) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * sin(radians(venue_address_lat)))) AS distance 
FROM car_offer JOIN venues_infos ON car_offer.venues_infos_id = venues_infos.venue_id WHERE (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(venue_address_lat)) * cos(radians(venue_address_lng) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * sin(radians(venue_address_lat)))) < 1.5
AND car_offer.offer_date = CURDATE()
AND venue_address_postcode = 1020
OR car_offer.offer_date = '0000-00-00'
ORDER BY distance, offer_price_small LIMIT 0,30";
```

The `lat, lng` in the database is from Google Maps, so this should be accurate.

Comment: *What*'s not working about it? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: no. i get a result list, but the order of the list is not by distance, the order is something else (no structure in the order)

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231167/aliases-not-working-in-order-by-clause I would have expected you to get error 1054 here - do you have a column called distance in one of the tables in the query?

Comment: No i don't. I name the formula in the query as "distance"

Comment: Out of interest, is it the alias that causes the problem? i.e. if you repeat the expression that comprises the alias in the ORDER BY clause instead of using the alias, do you get the expected results?

Comment: can you create a fiddle, or show some example input data and result with this failing? Also, what version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better of using a outer query in this case and then do the `order by` in outer query like below. (OR) you can use the same `distance` calculation expression in your `order by`. Notice I have moved the `distance < 1.5` from inner to outer query. Moreover, I am in doubt whether you can use `distance` in your `order by` clause like the way you are using (mean in the same query level unless it's from a derived table expression) since `distance` is a column alias.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(venue_address_lat)) * cos(radians(venue_address_lng) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * sin(radians(venue_address_lat)))) AS distance 
FROM car_offer 
JOIN venues_infos 
ON car_offer.venues_infos_id = venues_infos.venue_id 
WHERE car_offer.offer_date = CURDATE()
AND venue_address_postcode = 1020
OR car_offer.offer_date = '0000-00-00'
) tab
WHERE distance < 1.5
ORDER BY distance, offer_price_small 
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: I think you are better off using the same `distance` calculation expression in your `order by` (or just use `HAVING`)